# String output to MS-WORD has too many new lines

Tags: ms-word

This is my program window... The box in questions is the one labeled "INVESTIGATION" and "DISPOSITION".

When text is entered into the multiline textbox it is output in the DOCX file and it adds extra new lines... If a line is entered right below the original line it is a single extra new line. If it is spaced by one line it adds in two new lines. I figure it is something with the textbox properties or the output argument not playing well with the string. I have included pictures of the Form as it looks to the user. The builder code. The word document which shows the problem and the textbox properties. I want new lines in the investigation and disposition textbox to display how they are in the GUI and not have the extra new line. Any pointers?

I cant post images yet but you can view the images at the DOCX discussion board here https://docx.codeplex.com/discussions/658603

I hope its clear that I want it to display just as it is in the GUI:

```
A
A

A
```

should not look like it does in the last image where it is:

```
A

A



A
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You can replace the new lines with vertical tab `invest = invest.Replace("\r\n", "\v")` or `invest = invest.Replace("\n", "")`

Comment: I just tried that and I entered "AddLineNs(invest.Replace("\r\n", "\v"));"

Comment: Can someone chime in on this please?